# uninstall open suse from ubuntu system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Trying to dual-boot opensuse tumbleweed with a pre-existing 64-bit ubuntu 16.04 on gpt nmve-drive. Unhappily, I installed the opensuse system with the legacy grub bootloader rather than as a uefi-system, and have run into boot-problems.

Here's the current set-up:

```
azed@azed-H270N:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for azed: 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CFB16A8E-384A-4AD4-B14B-62F840FB7E73

Device             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1026047   1024000  500M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1026048 158722047 157696000 75.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3 158722048 183298047  24576000 11.7G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 183298048 235724799  52426752   25G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5 235724800 342421503 106696704 50.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 342421504 342441983     20480   10M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p7 342441984 405512191  63070208 30.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 405512192 500117503  94605312 45.1G Linux filesystem
azed@azed-H270N:~$
```

p2 is an ntfs-partition (no windows), Xenial is on p4-5. p6 is flagged "bios_legacy" and is tiny. Opensuse is on p7-8

At present, the boot is being handled by the opensuse system. I get the impression that the presence of the legacy grub bootloader is suppressing the uefi boot-system (I don't have a uefi boot-option - say, a drive tagged as "uefi" - in the BIOS system at boot)

**Question**:

If I delete the opensuse partitions, will the system revert to a uefi boot, or will I just be stuck with a system I can't boot?

Answer (score 0):

If you had run in boot problems go ahead... delete suse partition and if necessasy fix the grub. But man I suggest you to back up your ubuntu data than delete ubuntu and suse partition and do a fresh install of ubuntu. This way its more easy to avoid unnecessary mess.

Comment: I wanted to avoid completely rebuilding my system

Answer (score 0):

You've (accidentally?) activated your Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which is seldom a good idea. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for details. Your first step should be to disable the CSM. This should get your Ubuntu EFI-mode GRUB back in control of the computer. Once you boot Ubuntu, you can run `sudo update-grub` and, with any luck, it will detect your OpenSUSE installation and present it as a boot option.

Another possibility is to use my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) If you go this route, your best bet is to download the USB flash drive or CD-R version, prepare a boot medium with it, and boot it. rEFInd will probably detect both Ubuntu and OpenSUSE and give you options to boot both. You can then install rEFInd using the Ubuntu PPA, Debian package, or RPM, depending on which distribution you want to handle the installation and you preferences.

It may also be possible to adjust the boot order without completely disabling the CSM. To do this, you'll need to either boot Linux in EFI mode and use the `efibootmgr` tool, or use the firmware's setup utility to adjust the boot order. To use `efibootmgr`, you'd type `sudo efibootmgr` to see the current boot order, then change it with the `-o` option so that `ubuntu` is the first option. Different computers' firmware setup utilities vary in detail, so I can't provide specific instructions for them. They often (but not always) provide a way to adjust the boot order, so if you can find such an option, you should be able to use it to move the `ubuntu` item to the top of the boot order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. CSM is enabled by default in my BIOS. To disable it, I have to switch on another BIOS-option "Windows 8/10 features". But with this option selected the system seems to assumes I have a windows system installed (I haven't). For this or whatever reason, with "Windows 8/10 features" selected it boots into BIOS with no drive shown in the "boot-priorities"-section.